# what‘s the properites order in spring boot when import XML configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I can define an externalized configuration with this.

```
@Configuration
public class PropertiesConfig {
    @Configuration
    @PropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
    @Profile("test")
    static class DefaultConfig {

}
```

Also I can import a xml configuration using `@ImportResource`
In xml I also define an externalized configuration with this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <bean id="testProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:staging.properties"/>
    </bean>

    <context:property-placeholder order="1" properties-ref="testProperties"/>
</beans>
```

test.properties have `url=www.facebook.com`
staging.properties have `url=www.google.com`

It seems using `${url}` always got url of test.properties. 
How using xml configuration to cover the @PropertySource?

Comment: Why would you mix XML configuration with annotation based configuration? If you want a test mode to use different property values, use the Profile feature of String Boot: [Spring Boot Reference Guide - 25. Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html)

Comment: If not mistaken, the Annotation configuration overrides the XML configuration. This is the reason of your "unexpected" behaviour.

Comment: The reason is actually that nothing is merged. You actually end up with 2 `PropertySourcePlaceHolderConfigurer` instances. The first one, through annotations, the second one through XML. They aren't merged into 1. So basically the first one that sees the `${url}` will replace it, making it undetectable for the other one.

Comment: OK. It seems that change the order is difficult. I'll use the best practice of the spring boot. Thank you, guys.